# Multiple options in select in php form

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have this simple code in my product_form.tpl php file of opencart 2.3:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
<?php if ($type) { ?>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Flower</option>
<option value="0">Plant</option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="1">Flower</option>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Plant</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Everything fine and simple, but i need at least 1 more option for this select to add:

```
<option value="2">Bouquet</option>
```

Could you please tell me how this should look like in case of 3 options... Thanks in advance!

Comment: `case of 3 options...` -> what are those three options?

Comment: What are the possible values of `$type`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is exactly.  Did you try adding this option to your code?  Did that not work in some way?

Comment: I need my $type to get 0 / 1 or 2 value of option. In my example I have 2 options with 0 and 1. I need to add one more option in the select to receive value == 2. So i need to get option value="2" be "selected"

Comment: @Sepika `if - elseif - else`? Or `switch`? But you chose a bad approach, you dont need to show many times whole set of options, you just need to add 'selected' text to the correct one.

Comment: @panther i've tried elseif, but got mistakes - my php  knowledge is not enough( Switch method i don't know how to use here(

Comment: @Sepika: see my answer below, you don't need conditions here.

Comment: Why don't you add another option value for your select menu from admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose a bad approach as I wrote in comment under question.

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" <?php echo isset($type) && $type == 1 ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Flower</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo isset($type) && $type == 0 ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Plant</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo isset($type) && $type == 2 ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Bouquet</option>
</select>
```

Another way is using array and write the dropdown using foreach loop.

`isset($type)` can be taken above the code, you need to check if variable exists to prevent notice of undefined variable.

There can be something like

```
$type = isset($type) ? $type : NULL; // or any default value like 0
```

In `options` then will be just `<?php echo $type == 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the most comfortable way in my case! Perfect!

Comment: @Sepika: ideal solution is to create an array with items and use foreach loop, but for your case, for beginner it seems to be cleaner and easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to just write some structured code..

```
<?php
 $options = array(
        "1" => "flower",
        "0" => "Plant",
        "2" => "Bouquet",
        "3" => "Rock"
 );
 $currentval = 2;
?>

<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
   <?php
   foreach($options as $val => $label):
    ?>
      <option value="<?=$val;?>" <?=$currentval == $val ? 'selected' : ''?>><?=$label;?></option>
   <?php
    endforeach;
   ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a siwtch case block instead of bunch of if's you can check the documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_switch.asp and you can compare the value of $type more organized ! Good Luck !

Comment: You don't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to go this way, then:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
<?php if ((int)$type === 0) { ?>
<option value="2">Bouquet</option>
<option value="1">Flower</option>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Plant</option>
<?php } elseif ((int)$type === 1) { ?>
<option value="2">Bouquet</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Flower</option>
<option value="0">Plant</option>
<?php } elseif ((int)$type === 2) { ?>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Bouquet</option>
<option value="1">Flower</option>
<option value="0">Plant</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

But I would suggest using the way Jelmer Jellema suggested.

Comment: why cast though?

Comment: Just because == and === may cause confusion for a beginner, made it clear that the code will work.

Comment: @Darker: how you will add another 3 items? Or ten items? :-)

Comment: @panther look at what I suggested at the end of the answer. I totally agree and suggest to use other approaches. But just for the OP's reference, provided this way to make it work.

Comment: @Darker: you have two 'selected' options in last condition. It's the result of this bad approach, you can make many mistakes when you need to add a new item this way.

Comment: @panther my bad, thanks for noticing. Yes, it's a bad approach. Let's not communicate it anymore. OP wanted a solution, I provided a solution to his current code, but a dirty one. Nothing to talk about more.